# Flurry / Google Analytics / Localytics bandwidth consumption on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, flurry-analytics, localytics

I'm choosing an analytics service for my iOS app. I want to track quite a lot of events and the app I'm developing is going to be used outdoors, so there will be no wi-fi connection available, and even the cellular connectivity can be of a poor quality.

Analytics is the only thing that requires network connectivity in my app. Recently I've checked how much traffic it consumes, and it consumes much more than I've expected. That was about 500KB for Google Analytics and about 2MB for Flurry, and that's just for a 2-minute long session with a few hundred events. It seems very inefficient to me. (Flurry logs a little bit more parameters, but definitely not 4 times more.)

I wonder — have anybody compared other popular analytics solutions for their bandwidth consumption? Which one is the slimmest one?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need real time data (and you probably don't with outdoor app), you can get the best network compression for Analytics by dispatching more hits at once to benefit from batching and compression. To do that set the dispatch interval to 30 minutes. The maximum size of uncompressed hit that analytics will accept is about 8k so you should be sending less then that. With compression that would bring it down to ~25% of the original size for individual hit assuming mostly ascii data. To generate 500k of data you should be sending few hundred hits individually. With batching and compression the hits will shrink down more efficiently. Usually batch of 20 hits will compress to less then 10% of the uncompressed size or about 800 bytes per hit at most. For further network savings just send less data per event or fewer events. Btw, Analytics has a rate limit of 60 tokens that are replenished at a rate of 1 hit every 2 seconds. If you are sending few hundred events in short period of time your data is likely getting rate limited.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/limits-quotas#ios_sdk

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so do I understand correctly that for Google Analytics each hit (e.g. a simple screen view) can weight about 800 bytes even if it is send in a compressed batch?

Comment: It really depends how much and what data you add to the hit. The metadata added by Analytics is minimal and is usually < 100 bytes. Your app can add other parameters like labels on the event or call stack for crash that will make the hit much bugger. Analytics will drop hits larger then 8k so your app has a limit on how much data it can add. 8k x 10% compression = 800 bytes of compressed data max per hit. This is rough estimate as the compression ration depends a lot on what data you will add to the hit. Simple screen view should be < 200 bytes unless you use really long screen/app name.